# identify smallest date in a dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

My data is arranged in dictionaries within dictionaries, like so:

```
dict = {subdict1:{}, subdict2:{},...}
```

where

```
subdict1 = { subdict_a: {"date":A, "smallest_date":False}, subdict_b : {"date":B, "smallest_date": False},...}
```

I'd like to loop through the subdictionaries a,b,c... and identify which of the dates A, B, C... is the smallest in each subdictionary, and change the value of 'smallest_date' to True.

How to approach this problem? I tried something like this, but couldn't quite finish it:

```
for subdict_number, values1 in dict.items():
    smallest_date = None
    for subdict_alphabet, values2 in values1.items():
        if smallest_date == None or smallest_date > values2["date"]
            smallest_date = values2["date"]
            smallest_subdict = subdict_alphabet
```

And then some magic where as the loop within subdict closes sets

```
dict[subdict][smallest_subdict]["date"] = smallest_date
```

and then continues to the next subdict to do the same thing.

I can't finish this. Can you help me out? A completely different approach can be used, but as a beginner I couldn't think of one.

Comment: `dict[subdict][smallest_subdict]["date"] = smallest_date` should probably be `dict[subdict_number][smallest_subdict]["smallest_date"] = True`.

Comment: What do you mean by "smallest" date? Do you mean oldest or newest? Are they datetime objects?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to keep the naming explanatory.

Given the input dictionary:

```
main_dict = { 'subdict1' : {'subdict_1a': {"date":1, "smallest_date":False},
                        'subdict_1b' : {"date":2, "smallest_date": False}},
          'subdict2': {'subdict_2a': {"date":3, "smallest_date":False},
                        'subdict_2b' : {"date":4, "smallest_date": False}}}
```

Iterate through the subdicts and declare variables:

```
for subdict in main_dict:
    min_date = 10000000
    min_date_subsubdict_name = None
```

Iterate through the subsubdicts and determine the minimum

```
    for subsubdict in main_dict[subdict]:
        if main_dict[subdict][subsubdict]['date'] < min_date:
             min_date = main_dict[subdict][subsubdict]['date']
             min_date_subsubdict_name = subsubdict
```

Inside the first loop, but outside the second loop:

```
    main_dict[subdict][min_date_subsubdict_name]['smallest_date'] = True
```

This should return the output maindict:

```
{'subdict2': {'subdict_2a': {'date': 3, 'smallest_date': True}, 'subdict_2b': {'date': 4, 'smallest_date': False}}, 'subdict1': {'subdict_1a': {'date': 1, 'smallest_date': True}, 'subdict_1b': {'date': 2, 'smallest_date': False}}}
```